# Strange end-of-input error in Ruby

Tags: ruby

just written a really basic bit of Ruby code, and I can't seem to see what the error is finding wrong with it. I have already tried deleting and redoing all of the 'end' keywords, nothing seems to crack it.

I'm a beginner, so it may be something I haven't noticed. All help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
def is_a_prime(n)
    for 2.upto(n) do |x|
        return false if n % x == 0  
        return true
    end
end
puts is_a_prime(4)
```

Comment: As a note, `for` is hardly ever used in Ruby. This is because there's usually other methods that are far better suited to the task, like the `upto` one you're trying to use here.

Comment: By the way, once you decide exactly how you want your function, you should put it in the `int` class. Open up the class with `class int`, just as if it were a function and put the whole `is_prime` function inside it. Replace any reference to `n` with `self`. The function doesn't need a parameter. After that you can just call `4.is_prime?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the fix :

```
def is_a_prime(n)
  2.upto(n) do |x|
    return false if n % x == 0
  end
  true
end
puts is_a_prime(4)
# >> false
```

I'd write this *prime number check* code as :

```
def is_prime? n
  2.upto(n-1) { |x| return false if n % x == 0 }
  n > 1
end

is_prime? 5 # => true
is_prime? 4 # => false
is_prime? 7 # => true
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank-you so much for your quick and concise answer. i'm still getting used to Ruby, so your help is much appreciated!

Comment: This solves the syntax error, but this code won't compute whether something is a prime or not.

Comment: @Mischa I thought OP want to remove error not the logic.

Comment: At the end you can do `n > 1`, then you don't need the `c` variable.

Comment: In a code review I'd recommend *not* using `;` and `{...}`. `;` just allows the code to be less readable by obscuring the `return`, and if it's a multiple-line block then `do/end` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `for` keyword, and move the `return true` line down below the first `end`.

Comment: It would help if you'd show what you mean rather than just say. "A picture is worth..."

Answer (score -1):

Keyword `return` should be avoided when possible. Whether you think you need `return` it basically means that you are stuck with a wrong code design.

```
def is_a_prime(n)
  ! (2...n).each do |x| 
      break nil if (n % x).zero?
  end.nil?
end
puts is_a_prime(4)
puts is_a_prime(7)
```

Or:

```
def is_a_prime(n)
  ! (2...n).any? do |x| 
      (n % x).zero?
  end
end
```

Comment: Any reference for your claim that the use of `return` keyword should always be omitted? And that it's bad design if you *do* use it?

Comment: @Mischa I bet I saw this somewhere said by Matz, but I can’t google this reference now. I will soften the wording, albeit my experience yells it’s true :)

Comment: `return` is extremely useful, especially in guard clauses. A blanket statement that `return` should be avoided doesn't help, instead explain when and why `return` should be used.

Comment: @theTinMan I obviously can’t “explain when and why `return` should be used” because I never use `return` and happy with that.

Comment: Artificially ignoring the appropriate uses of `return` can turn what should be simple code into convoluted workarounds. It's better to understand when and why it should be used.

Comment: @theTinMan It happens naturally, not artificially. I consider using `return` a bad practice, you might think the other way round. Unless you provide any example of the code that is more readable with `return`s I won’t change my mind.

Comment: @mudasobwa You might find this cop relevant: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/rubocop/Rubocop/Cop/Style/GuardClause